# When my LG monitor sleeps I have no audio, (has built-in speakers)

Tags: display, sleep, speakers, standby, mediamonkey

I have an LG Ultra-wide series display (34UC97).

**When it sleeps, I have no audio.**

How can I prevent this to happen.
I usually listen to music all-day, yet no need to prevent the monitor from sleeping(don't need the screen).

I think there should be some screen modes or configuration helping on this.

```
LG 34UC97

Windows 10,

MediaMonkey
```

Comment: I doubt whether this is possible.

Comment: doubt on sleeping or a proper solution?

Comment: Proper solution.

Comment: If anyone thought the issue isn't because of the screen, consider MediaMonkey... I still not sure on the exact reason.

Comment: I see. still hopeful to find a solution.